# Differences when calling dll:s from service and application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll, service

My team and I are working with a windows service which calls a dll from an external program. The dll in the external program acts as a database where values can be stored and retrieved. Each value is identified with a string (sort of like a dictionary).

We can’t, however, set values in the database in the dll from our service. We get no errors, the values simply does not appear in the database.  When we run the exact same code as in our service as a console application it works fine.

I realize that this is a pretty broad question but does anyone recognize this problem or know any key differences between calling dll:s from services and from applications?

We have tried to run the service as local service, local system and administrator. The service is running on an virtual machine accessed through remote desktop.

Comment: Does the dll store data in a separate database or in-memory?

Comment: Just guessing as, yes, this is a very broad question, check the DLL code and make sure it's not doing anything GUI-centric like writing to the Console or popping up a Windows form.

Comment: @Saravana, I think it stores in memory. The database is only alive as long as it is in use by anyone.

Comment: @Steve Danner, I don't have access to the code of the dll but don´t think that it does any GUI activity.